# jQuery Themes to Richfaces components

Tags: java, jquery-ui, jsf, richfaces, themes

Can someone tell me whether the jquery themes can be applied to richfaces components.
To be specific I am now using dataTable and dataScoller components of Richfaces. I was able to add ui-widget-header to the column header but but was not able to add other theme class such as ui-corner-all to the dataTable. 
I even with the help of a js file successfully added ui-button themes for the dataScroller buttons. But when the dataTable get rendered with the click of the dataScoller the basic blue color theme gets applied.

Can somebody tell whether I can apply the themes of jQuery to the above components and other components of richfaces.

Note :: I have already used rich:jquery but it is not yelding any result.

Comment: Just FYI, PrimeFaces natively supports jQuery UI themeroller.